# What are the differences between Firefox and Chrome in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

There seem to be a number of differences (beyond performance of course) between both browsers when using Javascript. I am not even sure those are bugs or indeed different evaluations. In my applications (large, complex IDEs) I noticed here and there that Chrome is doing things different:

- Array::indexOf and sorting appears different (hard to isolate for me)
- scripts dealing with blur and focus seem to be different
- a number of other minor issues with CSS
- some other issues I can't remember of right now. The point of this post is to figure out what's different, nothing else :-)

I am also not really sure that the Chrome differences are really my faults and so I was wondering there things to know about Chrome vs FF when it comes to Javascript. My test-units do run all fine except in Chrome...

I did search a lot but I couldn't find any recommendation, guide or simple cheat list; possibly some folks here know better :-)

(ff/chrome version doesn't seem to matter)

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very large question as each are built on different frameworks and therefore support functions differently, especially once you start going back a few versions.

But here is a simple page that lets you dig into the differences of each.

http://caniuse.com/#compare=firefox+42,chrome+47 (change versions to whichever you want)

[image]

This is a small portion and you can already see there are too many differences for anyone here to list.

Comment: Note: if you like the color red try checking the IE6 box as well

Answer (score 1):

In addition to canIuse, there's also kangax's [compatibility tables](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/). However your question appears to be geared more towards an under-the-hood implementation comparison, I can't help you there. Anything not in the spec (or marked as implementation-defined) is fair game: for instance object property order is not guaranteed but both seem to maintain insertion order when iterating via `for...in`.