# Intl.NumberFormat : "RangeError maximumFractionDigits value is out of range"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am receiving this error with the following code in React Typescript. What input parameter could cause this error and how can I resolve it? It seems to have issue with Intl.NumberFormat parameters.

Trying to find input parameter causing this in our Rollbar error logging application. Its not showing yet, what input parameter was, it happens rarely.

> Error: RangeError maximumFractionDigits value is out of range.

```js
const formatCurrency = (item: number) => {
  const currencyFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'USD',
    maximumFractionDigits: 0,
  });
  return item == null ? '' : currencyFormat.format(item);
}
```

Note: seems to occur in Mozilla Firefox, not Chrome. Not sure if it makes a difference for this case

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
```

[What are the differences between Firefox and Chrome in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31864756/what-are-the-differences-between-firefox-and-chrome-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the following option set:

```
const formatCurrency = (item: number) => {
  const currencyFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'USD',
    minimumFractionDigits: 0,
    maximumFractionDigits: 0,
  });
  return item == null ? '' : currencyFormat.format(item);
}
```

Note the addition of `minimumFractionDigits: 0`.

There is a large body of business logic that determines what default values are, according to various customs. The XML representing that logic for USD currency looks like this:

```
<CcyNtry>
  <CtryNm>UNITED STATES OF AMERICA (THE)</CtryNm>
  <CcyNm>US Dollar</CcyNm>
  <Ccy>USD</Ccy>
  <CcyNbr>840</CcyNbr>
  <CcyMnrUnts>2</CcyMnrUnts>
</CcyNtry>
```

The `<CcyMnrUnts>2</CcyMnrUnts>` part is what specifies the default value for `minimumFractionDigits`

An `Intl.Numberformat` object of style "currency" and currency "USD" has an implied default `minimumFractionDigits` of `0`, and you cannot have a maxiumum that is lower than the minimum.

xml spec: https://www.six-group.com/dam/download/financial-information/data-center/iso-currrency/lists/list-one.xml

mozilla article explaining implementation logic: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat#currency_formatting